# Unable to Activate worklight project

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

I have been using worklight since december this year,it was working fine but then suddenly from the last few days whenever I run as build and deploy my project it shows Activating Workligth Project and stops there. So I am unable to run and test my projects.Please Help! I have reinstalled eclipse already ,changed my workspace but its still not working.

Answer (score 0):

1. Provide any errors you see in the Eclipse console as well as the server logs.
2. Verify it is not originating from your project - create a new project.
3. Verify you are **not** using Java 8 - use either 6 or 7.